# C#. Как организовать меню при нажатии на форму программы

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии мышкой на определенную область формы, появлялось диалоговое окно?

Comment: обработать клик по форме и показать окно?

Comment: Именно. Там например в определенное место(ну по координатам например)

Comment: ну в обработчике клика получайте координаты и вперед

Comment: В заколовке у вас "меню", в тексте вопроса - "диалоговое окно". Может вам контекстное меню нужно по клику правой кнопкой мыши?

Comment: Ну в иделе контекстное меню

Comment: если я правильно понял, то [вот ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/5.4.php)